# MATLAB: Randomly selecting to round up/down each element of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a `120x1 double` array which only contains the values 1, 0.5, and 0.

It's easy to round the 0.5 values all up using the `ceil` function, or all down using the `floor` function. However, I want to randomly decide between rounding up to 1 or down to 0 for each of the `0.5` values in the vector, while leaving all the `1` and `0` elements the same.

Is there a way to do this without looping through each element of the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following steps:

1. find out at which indices the `0.5` entries are in your original array
2. generate a random number between 0 and 1 for each of those entries
3. `round` those newly generated numbers and assign them to the original array

---

```
% generate demo data
n = 120;
v = [0, 0.5, 1];
data = v(randi(length(v), n, 1))';

% randomly round up or down the 0.5 entries
zero_point_five_idx = find(data==0.5);
data(zero_point_five_idx) = round(rand(size(zero_point_five_idx)));
```

---

even simpler: generate either a `0` or `1` randomly for each of the `0.5` entries:

```
possible_values = [0,1];
zero_point_five_idx = find(data==0.5);
data(zero_point_five_idx) = possible_values(randi(length(possible_values), size(zero_point_five_idx)));
```